# Spark Structured Streaming - aggregate over last 20 seconds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

What is the proper way to implement sliding window based aggregations over last 20 seconds prior incoming event's 'timestamp' value in SPARK v. 2.2.0?

The case is pretty simple - every time an event arrives, i need to check whether there were any other event of this kind, during the previous $timestamp - 20 seconds. To make it simple - i can ignore late coming events (no watermarking needed).

At the moment, by defining a window like that: `window($"timestamp", "20 seconds")`, i'm getting results with fixed start/end timestamps (every 20 sec starting from every minute:00sec). Essentially what i need are aggregations over periods defined by:

- window.end = event.timestamp
- window.start = event.timestamp - 20
  seconds

Please take a look at the simple example that i'm working with:

Use linux netcat tool to generate words on a given socket number by issuing a command:

```
nc -lk -p 9999
```

Paste the following scala script into a `spark-shell`:

```
val lines = spark.readStream.
  format("socket").
  option("host", "localhost").
  option("port", 9999).
  option("includeTimestamp", true).
  load()

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val windowedCounts = lines.
    groupBy(
        window($"timestamp", "20 seconds"), 
        $"value").
    agg(count($"value") as "count", last($"timestamp") as "last_ts", first($"timestamp") as "first_ts").
    select($"window.start", $"window.end",  $"last_ts", $"first_ts", $"value", $"count")

val query = windowedCounts.writeStream.
  outputMode("complete").
  format("console").
  option("truncate", false).
  start()
```

By generating a random 'words' in your netcat window you'll notice something similar to the following:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|start              |end                |last_ts            |first_ts           |value|count|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|2017-10-11 11:21:00|2017-10-11 11:21:20|2017-10-11 11:21:02|2017-10-11 11:21:17|word |7    |
|2017-10-11 11:21:20|2017-10-11 11:21:40|2017-10-11 11:21:21|2017-10-11 11:21:21|word |1    |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

'word' generated at 11:21:21 falls into a new time window and thus 'count' equals just one. However i'd like it to be 8, because there were 8 events during last 20 seconds (first one with timestamp 11:21:02).

How would you implement sliding window based on event time in Spark Structured Streaming v. 2.2.0? Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: @raam86 i'd like to have an aggregation every time an event appears. Timestamp of the aggregation itself is not reallly important. Important thing is - how many events of that kind occured 20s before. In my app, i have to generate an alarm only if  there weren't any other event of this kind in last 20 seconds.

Comment: you use `window` functions to group by event time, in this case you want to group by something else, maybe event name, you can later put these counts somewhere and watch the counts

Comment: @raam86 So i should just `filter()` out or better `remove()` messages older than 20s from my dataframe and `groupby()` without window function inside? Will that be the proper way to handle it?

Comment: I am not sure you will _have_ to remove the messages but I would start with group by the proper property and then find a way to go over values that didn't change in the last 20 seconds, you might want to create a different streaming app for that or even do it inside a database

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else is looking for an answer. You can pass slide duration to the window function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#window-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-